# How to disable options method from cors in get method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I don't want to allow options method when i call get or post method from react js.

But when i call get method first it calls options method and return 204 status code.

my code is:

```
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the express router to do this.

Example:

```
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
var router = app.Router();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

router.options('/', cors())
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@dvelasquez/handle-an-options-request-with-cors-in-node-js-f3f81c5a7494

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CORS`.and install CORS. And allow the GET method

```
let cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
    next(); 
});
```